# How can I make my program display the user's name from the database in JtextField?

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, jtextfield

I'm making a program where you login and it takes you into a into a different frame after you log in.. That part of the program works, but I'm having trouble getting it to return the user's name and other data from the database. It connects to the database, but it won't return the information inside JTextField. If I can find out how to do firstName, I can figure out the rest. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and SQLite Manager as the database.
There are 2 tables
Login (username,password)
Student(SID,firstName,GradeLevel, and more)
Also username is there ID start with an S (like S01 and so forth).
Here's the code.

```
public class student extends JFrame {
private JTextField textField;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                student frame = new student();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void ShowInfo() {

try{


    String query="SELECT firstName From Student,Login Where firstname=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, "firstName");
    ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
    textField.setText(rs.getString("firstName"));
        System.out.print(""+textField);
    }ps.close();
    conn.close();
    } catch ( Exception ex)
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
}


}
```

}

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is the problem in getting the correct data from the database? Or is it in displaying the data? As a side recommendation, please learn and follow java code formatting rules, especially on how to correctly indent code, and naming rules. Your current code violates these, making it hard for us to understand, and why make it harder for us to be able to help you?

Comment: Other side recommendations: Don't use `null` layouts and setBounds. While it seems easier initially to create gui's like this, in the long run it is much more difficult.

Comment: I'm having problems with displaying the data.

Comment: displaying data in your textfield?

Comment: Yes, it's not displaying it at all.

Comment: `System.out.print(""+textField);`  are you getting this output from the showinfo method

Comment: I'm not getting it at all.

Comment: im trying to help you with your code can u tell me if u are getting the joption pane with the exception.

Comment: I'm not even getting the exception. Am I possibly getting an empty string or is my query statement wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ShowInfo() {

try{
    String query="SELECT firstName From Student,Login Where firstname=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, "firstName");
    ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) {
    textField.setText(rs.getString(1));
    System.out.print(""+textField); //you are getting data
    }ps.close();
    conn.close();
    } catch ( Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex); //you have a error
}
}
```

there were sevral thing which were wrong in the code. first one is there should be something wrong with  sql statment  `Student,Login Where firstname`.
you should change this line `textField.setText(rs.getString(1));`
and you have a `while loop` to extract the data but and you are planning on having a `textfield` to store data. that is pointless if you are expecting more than one output from your resultset you need something more than a jtextfield maybe a jtable. bt i have changed your while loop to a  `if loop`  to get one single output from the resultset.and the other thing i notice in your application is you are not calling the `showInfo` method.

Comment: at windowload or i dont recommend this bt u can call this at constructor

Comment: `public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        showInfo();
    }`